# Exporting to CSV/Excel file in django from using raw sql

Tags: python, django, excel, csv, django-views

Am having issues generating excel/csv files in django mainly because am querying the database using raw sql(directly). I only have access to the database and not the model classes. Here is my code snippet.

I get an Error **'dict' object has no attribute 'todo_job'**

### View code

```
def query_to_dicts(query_string, *query_args):
"""Run a simple query and produce a generator
that returns the results as a bunch of dictionaries
with keys for the column values selected.
"""
    #log.debug(str(dir(connection)))
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    #log.debug(str(dir(cursor)))
    cursor.execute(query_string, query_args)
    #log.debug(cursor.rowcount)log
    col_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
    #log.debug(str(col_names))
    while True:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row is None:
            break
        
        row_dict = dict(izip(col_names, row))
        yield row_dict
    
    return

def excel(request):
    todo_obj = query_to_dicts('''SELECT * FROM users''')

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=elagu.xls'
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet("Todo")

    row_num = 0

    columns = [
        (u"ID", 6000),
        (u"t_stamp", 8000),
    
    ]

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True

    for col_num in xrange(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num][0], font_style)
        # set column width
        ws.col(col_num).width = columns[col_num][1]

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.alignment.wrap = 1

    for obj in todo_obj:
        row_num += 1
        row = [
            row_num,
            obj.todo_job,
            obj.created_date.strftime("%A %d. %B %Y"),
        ]
        for col_num in xrange(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)

    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

Comment: Please ask a question. What error are you having? Whats the issue?

Comment: I have , i get the error 'dict' object has no attribute 'todo_job'

Comment: Indeed, `dict`s have no `todo_job` attributes, to access `dict` values, you need to use the subscript operator, ex: `obj['todo_job']`

Comment: In which part exactly

Comment: Most like aumo is referencing where your code says `obj.todo_job`. There will also be a problem with `obj.created_date.strftime("%A %d. %B %Y")`. You will want change these, like aumo said, to `obj['todo_job']`and `obj['created_date'].strftime('%A %d. %B %Y)`. Please see the [python docs about dicts](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) for more info. @aumo, do you want to go ahead and post this an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access attributes of a `dict` object that do not exist at those places:

```
obj.todo_job
obj.creation_date
```

To access a `dict`'s values in Python, you need to use the subscripting operator (`[]`) with the relevant key as a string, which would give:

```
obj['todo_job']
obj['creation_date']
```

Refer to the [Python dict documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) for more information.

Comment: i get @aumo, but i end up with a **KeyError**  `'todo_obj'` when i use th subscripting operator **( [ ])**.

Comment: Then the `obj` `dict` as no key named `todo_obj`, try outputing the content of the `obj` `dict` to check its keys (ex: `return HttpResponse(str(obj))`), also, provide your models so there is more information to help you

Comment: return HttpResponse(str(obj)) succesfully outputs this **{'username': u'll', 'activation_key': u'', 'phone': u'', 'country': None, 'key_expires': None, 'is_active': True, 'email': u'll@ll.ll', 'is_superuser': True, 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 16, 14, 56, 50, 456459, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'address': u'', 'is_admin': True, 'fullname': u'', 'password': u'pbkdf2_sha256$12000$Zc2Ecsgh9KS1$1ThTx46Fq2+IbNE3qq1mLHcan51pcgXb5MGLZquhaqU=', 'id': 1, 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 16, 14, 56, 50, 456459, tzinfo=<UTC>)}**    . I have no models, am just connecting to the app psqldb directly